# Android java, duplicated code

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to create 4 graphs. I am a beginner and not sure how to create my graphs without duplicating the code.

Example graph 2

```
mChart2 = (LineChart)findViewById(R.id.resultGraph2);
mChart2.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
mChart2.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mChart2.setTouchEnabled(true);
mChart2.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);
mChart2.setDragEnabled(true);
mChart2.setScaleEnabled(true);
mChart2.setDrawGridBackground(true);
mChart2.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);
mChart2.setPinchZoom(true);
mChart2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
setData2();
mChart2.animateX(2500);
mChart2.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
mChart2.setExtraLeftOffset(5);
mChart2.setExtraBottomOffset(10);
```

Example graph 4

```
mChart4 = (LineChart)findViewById(R.id.resultGraph4);
mChart4.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
mChart4.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mChart4.setTouchEnabled(true);
mChart4.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);
mChart4.setDragEnabled(true);
mChart4.setScaleEnabled(true);
mChart4.setDrawGridBackground(true);
mChart4.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);
mChart4.setPinchZoom(true);
mChart4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
setData4();
mChart4.animateX(2500);
mChart4.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
mChart4.setExtraLeftOffset(5);
mChart4.setExtraBottomOffset(10);
```

They both have the same settings. 
Is there a better way of writing it, without needing to duplicate the code?

Comment: Have you ever heard of a function??

Comment: @JonathonReinhart user newbie :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
mChart2 = (LineChart)findViewById(R.id.resultGraph2);
mChart4 = (LineChart)findViewById(R.id.resultGraph4);
applySettings(mChart2);
applySettings(mChart4);

//...

void applySettings(LineChart chart)
{
    chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.